# Return last [0-9]\{6\} from a string with sed

Tags: regex, sed, pattern-matching

I want to pass a long list of filenames in the form

```
something_0230232_long_5160mK.csv
something_0230232_long-025160mK.csv
simething_0230342_lingk425460mK.csv
```

to sed (or similar linux shell tools) and get always the 
last array of digits before mK per line

This works, if there are exactly 6 digits. how can I enhance it for n digits?

```
echo "something_0230232_long_025160mK.csv" | sed -e "s/S.*\([0-9]\{6\}\)mK\.csv/\1/p"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution using GNU `grep`:

```
$ grep -Po '[0-9]+(?=mK)' file

5160
025160
425460
```

Explanation:

`-o` show only the part of the line that matches.

`-P`  use perl regexp.

```
[0-9]+     # Match a string of digits (at least one)
(?=mK)     # Followed by mK (positive lookahead)
```

---

And with `sed` *(since you asked)*:

`sed -E 's/.*[^0-9]([0-9]+)mK.*/\1/' file`

`-E` use extended regexp *(alias for `-r` but more portability).*

```
s/         # Subsitution -
.*         # Match everything
[^0-9]     # That's not a digit
([0-9]+)   # Capture the last digit string
mK         # Followed by the string mK
.*         # Match everything left
/          # Replace with -
\1         # The captured digit string only
/          #
```

Comment: Nice , thanks. your solution makes me remind how good lookahead is!

Comment: This was far beyond my imagination. I thought I would need sed. very elegant solution! thx.

Comment: I added how I would do it with `sed` but yes the `grep` solution is far more elegant :)

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with your `sed` command:

```
echo "something_0230232_long_025160mK.csv" |
sed -e 's/^.*[^0-9]\([0-9]\{1,\}\)mK\.csv/\1/'
```

Differences:

- Replace `S` with `^`.  This matches at the start (there is no `S` in the data, so the original would never match).
- Replace `6` with `1,`.  This means 'one or more digits' given the context (strictly, one or more repeats of the previous regex, but the previous regex was `[0-9]`).
- Insert the `[^0-9]` to stop the `.*` from being too greedy.  When the number of digits matched was fixed (`\{6\}`), the rigidity prevented the `.*` from being too greedy.  When you have two flexible ranges, the first will be the longest possible.  Without the `[^0-9]`, you get a `0` printed for the sample string.
- Drop the 'p' so the value is printed once.  Alternatively, keep the `p` and add `-n` as an option.

*Reminder to self: test before (or shortly after) you post.*

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "something_0230232_long_025160mK.csv" | sed 's/^.*_//' | sed 's/mK.csv//'
```

Comment: My example was not perfect. The _ is not always there.